# Dynamically insert data Flask SQL Alchemy

Tags: flask, dynamic, sqlalchemy

I have a model defined as below:

```
class DealData(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    deal_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('deals.id'))
    data1 = db.Column(db.Numeric(17,2))
    data2 = db.Column(db.Numeric(17,2))
    data3 = db.Column(db.Numeric(17,2))
    data4 = db.Column(db.Numeric(17,2))
    data5 = db.Column(db.Numeric(17,2))
    data6 = db.Column(db.Numeric(17,2))
    data7 = db.Column(db.Numeric(17,2))
    data8 = db.Column(db.Numeric(17,2))

class DataTitle(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    subVertical_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('sub_vertical.id'))
    businessModel_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('business_model.id'))
    data1 = db.Column(db.Numeric(17,2))
    data2 = db.Column(db.Numeric(17,2))
    data3 = db.Column(db.Numeric(17,2))
    data4 = db.Column(db.Numeric(17,2))
    data5 = db.Column(db.Numeric(17,2))
    data6 = db.Column(db.Numeric(17,2))
    data7 = db.Column(db.Numeric(17,2))
    data8 = db.Column(db.Numeric(17,2))
```

There is two table in this. The Data title will carry the title of the data, while the data table itself will be the table for the data.

How do I insert data into the dealData table dynamically? Some cases it might have 3 data, some case might be 5.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use a helper function like this to dynamically update data

```
def construct_update(table_name, where_vals, update_vals):
    query = table_name.update()
    for k, v in where_vals.items():
        query = query.where(getattr(table_name.c, k) == v)
    return query.values(**update_vals)
```

The function above returns a query that can be executed with:

```
table = db.Table('DealData')
where_columns = {"deal_id": 1}
update_columns = {"data1": data_to_update1, "data2": data_to_update2}
query = construct_update(table, where_columns, update_columns)

my_session = Session(engine)
result = my_session.execute(query)
my_session.close()
```

you can add as much or as little data as you want to "update_columns", because the **update_vals in the helper function will consume the entire dict. Dont forget to define which row you want to update using the "where_colums" dict